# Set up Spring Boot Data and Querydsl: Not generating metamodels (using Intellij IDEA)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to set up a project using Querydsl. I have tried to follow the official docs [v5.0.0](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/reference/html_single/#d0e147) and [v4.4.0](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.4.0/reference/html_single/#d0e137) but the metamodels do not get generated (except once, then I changed something, rebuilt, they disappeared, I changed back, and they did not reappear).
I think that IntelliJ IDEA has a role to play here as well.

Here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>querydsl</name>
    <description>A test for querydsl</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my test entity:

```java
package com.example.querydsl.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;
    @Getter @Setter
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And I have a repo for it

```java
package com.example.querydsl.repos;

import com.example.querydsl.entities.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {
}
```

Comment: JpaRepository is already including the `@Repository` annotation, you can remove it from your custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns into a rule, that minutes or hours after posting a question, I stumble upon the answer. After some more research and trial and error, I found the solution.

Playing around with dependencies in the pom.xml and constant building messed something up. So what I did was to set a fixed version of the QueryDSL to 5.0.0 and then do a `mvn clean compile`

So here's the dependency section of the pom.xml for clarity:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```